# Невожможно выбрать модификатор доступа класса

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой следующего рода: есть `public` класс. При попытке создать наследника с модификатором отличным от `public` пишет

> "modifier ... not allowed here".

Почитал в интернете нашел, что класс наследник может иметь уровень доступа такой же или "шире" чем родителя. При создании третего класса, который не являеться чьим-либо наследником, пишет

> "modifier ... not allowed here"

при `private`. При модификаторе `public` понятно (в одном java - файле может быть только один `private`), protected мне не нужен - наследников не будет. Все классы находятся в одном пекедже и одном файле (программа ведь учебная и небольшая). Проблемы нету только с package модификатором.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так.

```
package Animals;

  public class Bird {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
  }

  class Parrot extends Bird {
  }

  private class Cat {
  }
```

Comment: Вы бы код привели.

Comment: голосую за закрытие вопроса ввиду недостаточности подробностей

Comment: Сейчас добавлю код

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите. В таком виде `private` или `protected` классы `Parrot` и `Cat` были бы недоступны никому, даже методу `main` в классе `Bird`.

Без указания конкретного модификатора классы будут иметь package-видимость, то есть видимы для всех в пределах пакета `Animals` (кстати, пакеты именуют с маленькой буквы).

Для внутренних (inner) классов задание видимости уже имеет смысл: они могут являться деталями реализации внешнего класса, о которых не нужно знать окружающему миру. Т.е. такой код скомпилируется:

```
public class Bird {
    private class Cat {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Этот прием достаточно широко используется в классах, входящих в JDK. Например, список [`LinkedList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList) не показывает наружу деталь реализации - класс узла списка [`LinkedList.Node`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Node), поэтому объявляет его так:

```
public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    private static class Node<E> { ... }
}
```

Comment: То есть, в моем случае использовать inner - класс не стоит? Целесообразнее создать их с package - видимостью? И скажите, пожалуйста,  а почему в случае, если я сделаю bird protected выбивает ошибку?

Comment: Должен быть один public-класс в файле

Comment: это обязательное условие?

Comment: Понимаю, вопрос может показаться глупым, но рискнуть еще спросить Вас, когда действительно стоит использовать внутренние и вложеные классы?

Comment: если создать класс bird package, так же как и parrot, то прогамма будет работать, значит не обязательно создавать хотя бы один public, но если бы я создал его, то он был бы один, В это имели ввиду?